# Checking character hit test with all scene objects in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection, hittest

Ok heres my problem and it will take a bit to explain.

For class were developing an arcade game in AS3.  The university has an arcade machine and the OS on the machine was developed by our teacher and offers a software developer kit.  Its nothing crazy so most of it is fairly simple.  I just wanted to point this out mainly because instead of an ENTER_FRAME event and loop function Im using an override function called update() that the SDK offers to perform updates every frame.

Ok with that out of the way heres my issue.  I have a document class called GameState and this essentially handles the game while in that state.   In this class I setup the world and the character.  Right now its just 2 mountains, 2 castles, 3 islands and the character.

```
private function initWorld():void
    {
        trace("World has initiated");
        addChild(hazardArea)
        positionElement(hazardArea, 0, 560);

        addChild(mountainSideRight);
        positionElement(mountainSideRight, 730, 200)

        addChild(mountainSideLeft);
        positionElement(mountainSideLeft, 0, 200);

        addChild(castleOne);
        positionElement(castleOne, 5, 160);

        addChild(castleTwo);
        positionElement(castleTwo, 765, 160);

        addIslands();
    }
```

The position element is just a function that sets the x and y coordinates of the MC i added to the stage.  Now Ive also created an override on AddChild so that everytime I add a Child to the stage it saves it into an array I can access later:

```
override public function addChild(object:*):void
    {
        super.addChild(object);
        worldObjects.push(object);
    }
```

Ok and the three islands are added via addIsland which looks like this:

```
private function addIslands():void
    {
        var island:Array = Islands.getIslandCords();
        for (var x:int = 0; x < DiceNumbers.NUM_ISLS; x++) 
        {
            addChild(island[x].mc);
            positionElement(island[x].mc, island[x].x, island[x].y);

        }
    }
```

Islands is just a class that finds a position for my 3 islands with a bunch of math and stuff... doesn't really matter the array that is returned is just 3 objects that contain an instance of the moveclip and the x and y coords for it.

I also have a separate character class that represents my dwarf(the character in my game).  Theres nothing weird in the class except that i have a gravity system that looks like this:

```
var gravity:Number = 2;
public var moveX:Number = 300;
public var moveY:Number = 50;
public var xSpeed:Number = 0;
public var ySpeed:Number = 2;
public static const playerSpeed:Number = 3;
public var friction:Number = .75;
```

and then the update() function which I mentioned works like EVENT_FRAME loop, has this in it:

```
public function update():void
{
    xSpeed *= friction;
    moveX += xSpeed;
    moveY += ySpeed
    theDwarf.y += gravity;

    this.x = moveX;
    this.y = moveY;

    updateControls();
}
```

theDwarf is the instance of my dwarf movie clip and updateControls gives the functionality for my dwarf to move around.

Ok.... so finally in my GameState class under the update() function I call my collision class and pass the array with all of the objects from the scene to it. In this class I check for a collision:

```
public function checkCollision(listOfObjects:Vector.<MovieClip>):void
    {   

        for (var i:int = 0; i < worldObjects.length; i++) {
            if(worldObjects[i] is Player){

                var objOne:MovieClip = worldObjects[i];             
                for (var j:int = 0; j < worldObjects.length; j++){
                    if (j == i){
                        // elimates self comparisons.
                    }
                    else{
                        var objTwo:MovieClip = worldObjects[j];
                        checkIntersect(objOne, objTwo )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private function checkIntersect(player:MovieClip, objTwo:MovieClip):void
    {
        if(player.hitTestObject(objTwo)){
            player.ySpeed = -1;
        }
        else{
            player.ySpeed = 2;
        }
    }
```

AND my problem is this:  This funcion checks my player against EVERY object on the stage.  So even though my dwarf lands on 1 island hes not hitting the other 2 islands and so ySpeed keeps getting reset to 2.  If i get rid of the else statement my dwarfs gravity is never set back to 2 and he never falls again.  I CANNOT find a solution for this... ive tried so hard to find a way to get around this and im so stumped...  I want my dwarf to fall unless hes on one of my islands or a mountain.   I hope Ive been clear enough to explain my problem, this has now become a HUGE post... :D THANK YOU!

Comment: You have to break for loop if you hit object, so it won't do further checking and possible reset player speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better explain my comment from before, you have to change those last 2 function like this:

```
public function checkCollision(listOfObjects:Vector.<MovieClip>):void
{   

   OuterLoop: for (var i:int = 0; i < worldObjects.length; i++) {
        if(worldObjects[i] is Player){

            var objOne:MovieClip = worldObjects[i];             
            for (var j:int = 0; j < worldObjects.length; j++){
                if (j == i){
                    // elimates self comparisons.
                }
                else{
                    var objTwo:MovieClip = worldObjects[j];
                    player.ySpeed = checkIntersect(objOne, objTwo )
                    if (player.ySpeed == -1)
                        break OuterLoop;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private function checkIntersect(player:MovieClip, objTwo:MovieClip):int
{
    if(player.hitTestObject(objTwo)){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return 2;
    }
}
```

This can also be done better way. but this is quickest solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you!!  Your example didn't really work for me player is a private property of checkIntersect and doesn't exist in checkCollision, even though it could just be changed to objOne but even so, i tested that and my dwarf didn't fall at all.  HOWEVER! thanks to your logic i simply implemented it in a different way where checkIntersect returns a boolean, false if no hit or true if hit.  Then in checkCollision i create a boolean var called hit and then assign the checkIntersect return to it and create a similar if condition and if TRUE i simply return the function. Seems to work so far!!

Comment: Also, I would be really interested in how it can be done in a better way if you have time.